# Using usort on a php object not working

Tags: php

I cant seem to get this function to sort properly. Here is my code:

```
    function cmpPriceDesc($a, $b)   {
        return strcmp($a->product_price, $b->product_price);
     }

     usort($this->products, "cmpPriceDesc");
```

Is returning the following:

```
Array
    (
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_manufacturer_id] => 2
        [mf_name] => Karl
        ...
        [product_price]=> 127.445
    )
 [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_manufacturer_id] => 7
        [mf_name] => Karl
        ...
        [product_price]=> 13.445
    )
  [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_manufacturer_id] => 5
        [mf_name] => Karl
        ...
        [product_price]=> 13.445
    )
  [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_manufacturer_id] => 11
        [mf_name] => Karl
        ...
        [product_price]=> 18.000
    )
```

As you can see the the product price is not going from high to low. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: What do you think `strcmp` does?

Comment: I don't think using string comparisons for integer/decimal prices is the best idea.

Comment: As you can tell, im relatively new...so by all means feel free to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmpPriceDesc()` should follow [usort](http://php.net/usort)'s specs:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

It'd be as simple as:

```
function cmpPriceDesc($a, $b)   {
    return $b->product_price - $a->product_price;
}
```

I'm inferring you want higher values first given the *Desc* in the function name.

Comment: Thank you! You've been very helpful, not only did you give the answer but you explained it.